# Editing a product just shows a blank page

Tags: magento-2.1

In my Magento 2.1.1, every time I edit a specific product it will just show a blank page. This page is shown after hitting the edit link.

[image]

> [2016-11-06 06:18:14] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"site.site.ste/admin123/catalog/produc‌​t/edit/id/825/key/…;‌​:{"tags":["catalog_p‌​roduct"],"mode":"mat‌​chingAnyTag"},"is_ex‌​ception":false} []

Comment: There is any error from the log?

Comment: Ahmm what log do you mean? I mean a specific log

Comment: There is no log error. It just gives me a blank page whenever, I edit a certain product

Comment: [2016-11-06 06:18:14] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://site.site.ste/admin123/catalog/product/edit/id/825/key/5a58b88cc0278561e30c343fdaa36ac539cf02319923273aa05cb741cb6d5687/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []